# ISO of not recognized DVD

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dvd, iso-image, dd

I'm often dumping DVDs to ISO-files for backup by using `dd` on my linux machine. But now I've got a DVD in a filesystem that linux doesn't recognize. Still, I want to dump it's data in an *.img-file, but when I try `sudo dd if=/dev/sr0 of=Desktop/img.img bs=1M` it just says: `dd: failed to open '/dev/sr0': No medium found.`

I've also tried those I found in my `/dev/`-directory: `/dev/cdrom`, `/dev/cdrw`, `/dev/dvdrom` and `/dev/dvdrw`, all with the same error message. But there must be a way to dump the disc's contents to an img-file, doesn't it? Any ideas on how to do this are really appreciated.

Comment: If it can't be recognized, how can it be accessed?

Comment: Does it do the same thing (unrecognized)  if inserted into a dvd drive on a Windows system?

Comment: Yes, it does, there's a proprietary file system on the disc.